# Accidental branch merge into another branch

Tags: git, visual-studio-code

In VSC, it happens sometimes that I make some changes to branch X, stage, commit and push those changes, do a git status to make sure everything's ok, then switch to branch Y (the two branches are completely unrelated). All of a sudden, the new branch shows I have several commits - which I know should *not* be there. If I do push them, the next thing I know, branch X and branch Y have been merged together. This doesn't happen every time, but it is very painful when it does happen.

Can anyone help me understand why this is happening, so I can avoid it?

I went through the regular process:

1. make some changes to branch X, stage, commit and push those changes.
2. git status
3. switch to branch Y

I expected simply switching to branch Y, but now I have the content from branch X merged into branch Y.
I *never* gave the command to merge these branches.

Comment: Just rollback what you did

Comment: is your status clean? It will not happen without any command that the last commit of X also appears on Y

Comment: If you have a habit of working on multiple branches at once you might want to look into using git worktrees. Or at the very least have multiple checkouts of the repository. Sometimes it is just better to take precautions if it is something which have happened for you more than once :P

Comment: If you want to investigate why it happens you might want to look into the reflog of the branch which got the unexpected commits.

Comment: how are you performing those actions? Through VS Code UI? through commandline? Show the _exact_ steps

Comment: I've tried through the VSC UI AND through the command line, it doesn't make a difference. Mind you, I don't get this error EVERY time, just sometimes, with no warning. I use the same process every time, but I only get that error some times...
And, like I said, I switch or checkout branches, never work on several at the same time.